# Send a stream of response NodeJS ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I would like to send back to the client a stream of responses from [the npm twitter package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter).

The end-point looks like

```
var client = new Twitter({
 consumer_key: '',
 consumer_secret: '',
 access_token_key: '',
 access_token_secret: ''
});

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  const stream = client.stream('statuses/filter', {track: 'crypto'});
  stream.on('data', function(event) {
    res.status(200).json({tweet: event && event.text || 'nothing'})
 });
});
```

The server responds once to the client app and then gives an error that headers are already sent `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` , how do I respond with a stream?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So, use

```
res.write().
```

It does not end it, so you can add call it multiple times, while after res.json & res.send  you can't write to res more.

Comment: and call res.end() after you have sent all data.

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad Aadil Banara, and how do I get the response from the client side which is an angular app?
I am now looking into socketio actuallu

Comment: No need to do any different thing for this, just call in the same way as we call in angular, one way to call in angular is like this.
this.http.get('/app/test')
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => { this.output = data},
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('done')
      );

Comment: OK let me try it out

Comment: Thanks but I have achieved using socket.io